# Xamarin: how to create views / UI of an app dynamically from a Json

Tags: json, user-interface, xamarin, xamarin.forms, interpreter

Have you already developed a **Xamarin app whose views are generated from a Json** recovered when launching the application?

I met a client with this kind of need:

- they are developing a **web app to prototype the screens** by adding and positioning some **controls** (TextBox, Label, ...)
- this generates a **Json** that must be **interpreted** by the Xamarin app: this will build the different views dynamically
- in a first version, the **user's data would be stored locally** (through a file or SQLite) and synchronized "manually" when the device is connected to a computer
- the app will work on **Android** only in a first time, and then on **WPF**

The client has not yet decided between **Xamarin.Forms** or **Xamarin native**, but it's probably more interesting to do it through Xamarin.Forms, even if iOS is not required: this should make porting on WPF easier.

***Have worked on similar cases? Have you some recommendations? Are there plugins or patterns that could be used to simplify this development?***

I've found this [one](http://www.cazzulino.com/dynamic-forms.html), but it doesn't seem to be the same use.

There is also this [article](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/monotouch.dialog/json_element_walkthrough/) on iOS, but there is not the same thing on Android.

Answer (score 1):

This would in theory be possible using a massive code behind builder for a page but should NOT be done for a production app. Mobile apps have very specific requirements that need to be thought of before attempting.

Xamarin is great for simplifying code reuse, and if you use Xamarin Forms you can reuse the UI components for Enterprise apps.(the less fancy and pixel perfect the layouts need to be the better. )

Your client would be better served by making it a mobile compatible web page instead from the details you have shared.

Comment: Hi @rytan2005 thanks for your feedback!
I finally refused this client's project.
But concerning the context, it was not to create public apps, but internal/enterprise apps. I think they have made this choice because they need to be able to easily design and deploy "basic" apps, that must be powerful and able to access the devices API (photo, geolocation, ...)

Comment: So in that case, most "basic" apps are better if coded with set views. the issue with their plan was that they did have set views. Modifications are relatively quick in the Xamarin Forms but it already has a cost to the reusable UI.